# Disassembly of Visual Studio Intel compiler c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Most of my question is mentioned in the title of this question.

I recently wanted to learn (and play :-) ) with the Intel C++ Compiler, so I downloaded and plugged it into a Visual 2010 c++ (win32 console) project. I am just curious to look on the disassembly.

Most of the dissemblers cannot open produced code, so just asking does anyone known how to preview compiled code?

Thanks for help.

Comment: What about using the appropriate option to let the compiler produce assembly code. I just know, that it's `-S` for GCC, but I'm pretty sure there's a similar option available for the MSVC toolchain.

Comment: `dumpbin /disasm x.obj` does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `/Fa` on the command line to generate assembly language output.

Inside Visual Studio, pull up the properties page for your project, look in the `Output Files` section under `C/C++`, and turn on assembly language output:

[image]